# Google Slides App Script: get slideshow info?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am developing a feature on Google Slides App Scripts. API provides ability to add menus, sidebars, modify existing slides. But I do not see API for tracking of active slide index or any slideshow related info like full screen mode. Does anyone know if it is possible at all?

Comment: According to the documentation, there is no class of display properties - only classes and methods relating to design and data on the slides. You can get the `Presentation` which offers [methods for working on slides](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation) in the active presentation. You can also get the [Slide position](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide-position) as an Enum.

Comment: Thanks Brian. Tried that and it does not work unfortunately. Also I tried to recognize running presentation by accessing DOM directly from sidebar but was refused by iframes and different domains limitation.

Comment: I meant you could make your edits through apps script (indexing a particular slide), not getting access _while_ presenting. Sorry for the unclear suggestion. At this point, I don't think what you're looking for is possible.